# About general Homology with negative index

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $0 > n\in \mathbb{Z}$. I know, that in Singular Homology $ H_n(X)=0 $ for a toplogical space $ X \neq \emptyset $. If we now use a general Homology which satisfies the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms does this property also hold? If yes, how to prove? And if no, is there an example of a Homology theory which is non zero for negative $n$?

Furthermore if it is not zero, how does this affect the reduced homology?

Comment: Do the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms include the dimension axiom?

Comment: To my knowledge Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms are1. Homotopy 2. Excision 3. Dimension (let  P be the one point space then $ H_n (P) = 0 $ for all $n \neq 0$) 4.Additivity and 5. Exactness

Comment: The additivity axiom does not belong the "classic" axioms, but you should add all relevant information to your question. I asked for the dimension axiom just to verfiy that you do not consider *generalized homology theories*.

Comment: As far as I know the answer is no if you include the dimension axiom and yes if you exclude it; an easy example that does not satisfy the dimension axiom is $2$-periodic integral or rational cohomology, and a more interesting example is topological $K$-theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The "classical" Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms are homotopy invariance, exactness, excision and dimension. These describe *ordinary homology theories*. It is well-known that for finite CW-pairs the homology groups $H_n(X,A)$ are (up to natural isomorphism) uniquely determined by the coefficient group $G = H_0(*)$, where $*$ is a one-point space. In fact, they agree with the singular homology groups of $(X,A)$ with coefficients in $G$.
In particular $H_n(X,A) = 0$ for $n < 0$.

Beyond finite CW-pairs things are more sophisticated. In

> I.M. James and J.H.C. Whitehead, "Homology with zero coefficients", The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, Volume 9, Issue 1, 1958, Pages 317–320

one can find examples of non-trivial ordinary homology theories with zero coefficient group. There are *infinite CW-complexes* $X$ with nonvanishing homology groups. Making a dimension shift ($H'_n = H_{n+k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$) we can achieve that $H'_n(X) \ne 0$ for *negative* $n$. The theory $H'_*$ has coefficient group zero, if you do not like that consider $H'_* \oplus H^{sing}_*$, where $H^{sing}_*$ is singular homology with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients.

Comment: I was asked a similar question by a colleague recently so I was please to see such a neat answer. Bonus round: can you find an additive theory with similar properties?

Comment: @Tyrone The additivity axiom allows to prove uniquess for all CW-pairs (see Milnor's "On axiomatic homology  theory"). I do not know whether an additive theory can have nontrivial groups in negative dimension, but I would be surprised if there would be no such examples.